# scp command is not working for copying directory in linux

Tags: linux, scp

I am trying to copy selected entire directory from node1 to another node2 from jump instance by using below command but its throwing error. I am able to login to the node1 and from node1 I am also able to login to node2 and vice versa.

**Node1** and **node2**  are identical

```
scp -r -i abc.pem user1@node1:/abc/abc1/* user2@node2:/abc/abc1/*
```

**Error**:

> Permission denied (publickey). lost connection

Comment: You need to be able to login directly to node2, since `scp` relays via your local system.

Comment: Otherwise you have to execute `scp` on node1. And also have the secret key stored there too.

Comment: @arkascha  Is there another command which directly transfer file from node 1 to node 2?

Comment: Make sure SSH from the *local* node to node2 works, and don't put an asterisk in the path on the node2 (target) side (also, in some cases you'd need to quote the asterisk or other wildcards, but here it's probably fine as is - run the command with *echo" in front of it so see if the shell is expanding your "*"  when you didn't expect it).  I'd probably use -rpv instead of just -r.

Comment: None which does not have the same requirements. But what you _can_ do is this: you use `ssh` to login to node1, then from there you login to node2 and setup a ssh tunnel forwarding node2's ssh server to a local port on node1. How to setup such a tunnel is described in the manual pages. Then you can use `scp` on your local system and copy from `user1@node1` to `user2@node1` by specifying the port you setup the tunnel to, so that your transfer is actually tunneled to node2.

Comment: @AlexNorth-Keys I'd say it is pretty clear that the OP is _not_ able to connect to node2 directly.

Comment: How is this "programming related"? AFAICT, this is offtopic here.

Answer (score 1):

There is `-3` switch solving the authentication issue:

```
scp -3 -r -i abc.pem user1@node1:/abc/abc1/* user2@node2:/abc/abc1/*
```

This will authenticate to both machines from your workstation and is quite standard way of doing things, unlike the other hacks.

Answer (score 0):

the command
`scp user1@host1:file user2@host2:` tries to connect to host1, then to connect to host2 from host1. The error message you got indicates that you do not have permission for this connection.

A simple workaround is to transit via the local host to perform the copy:

```
ssh -i abc.pem user1@node1 tar c -C /abc/abc1 . | ssh -i abc.pem user2@node2 tar x -C /abc/abc1
```

Comment: Not at all. scp does not route via local node. He has said he can connect to node1 and to node2 without problem.The problem is that scp is implicitely trying to connect to node2 from node1. This is a classical problem that existed also for rcp.

Comment: Looks like you're right;  I just never interpreted the manpage that way.  Sorry about that.